# SQuirreL SQL Connecting to VJDBC database

Tags: sql, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to use SQuirreL SQL to connect to a VJDBC database.
Is there any way to change the login properties of Squirrel?

Let me explain in Java:
With the VJDBC driver, you login with these property keys.

```
Class.forName("de.simplicit.vjdbc.VirtualDriver").newInstance();
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty(VJdbcProperties.LOGIN_USER, "username");
prop.setProperty(VJdbcProperties.LOGIN_PASSWORD, "password");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url", prop);
```

If you login with just plain strings, it will error with "User is Null"

```
Class.forName("de.simplicit.vjdbc.VirtualDriver").newInstance();
Properties prop = new Properties();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");
```

So is there any way to make SQuirreL SQL login to the VJDBC server using those properties?

Comment: That is clearly a bug in VJDBC, drivers must support `getConnection` that takes a username and password as parameter. Have you tried adding the connection properties to the URL?

Comment: I tried adding the connection properties to the URL and it didn't work because of the way the driver parses the URL. I also looked through the code and it seems like it has to work that way. Thanks for the help.